# Local git repo inside windows dockerfile (Multimodule)

Tags: git, dockerfile, repository, local

`I have a spring boot code present in my D:\MY_POC\spring-boot-multi-module-maven-master (windows machine)
Through a dockerfile I want to create a git init in this directory and copy all the files to this repo locally. Then through dockerfile I want to access the code using git clone from this local repo and do maven install and build and then run the code.

I have done this coding with some google help. Is this correct?

## Use an OpenJDK 11 base image

FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11-slim AS build

## Set the working directory inside the container

#WORKDIR /app

## Install Git

RUN apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y git

## Initialize a new Git repository at the specified path

RUN git init /app/MY_POC

## Set Git user details

RUN git config --global user.email "Useremail@testorg.com" && 
git config --global user.name "User Name"

## Copy the source code to the container

COPY /MY_POC/spring-boot-multi-module-maven-master /app/MY_POC

## Set the working directory to the cloned repository

WORKDIR /app/MY_POC

## Add all files to the Git repository

RUN git add .

## Commit the files to the Git repository

RUN git commit -m "Initial commit"

## Build the application

RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

## Use Tomcat as the base image

FROM tomcat:9.0-jre11-slim

## Copy the built WAR file from the web module to the Tomcat webapps directory

COPY --from=build /app/MY_POC/web/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

## Expose the port on which Tomcat is listening

EXPOSE 8080

## Start Tomcat

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]`your text``